# Django MongoEngine/REST Framework ListFields

Tags: python, mongodb, rest

I need to store a list of numbers within a mongo db field and then present this via the REST framework.

So far everything (for all other fields) is working I just need to figure out the list as there is no direct option for the Django ORM.

**Serializes**

```
class tyre(serializers.Serializer):
    enabled = serializers.ListField()
    tyre_pressure = serializers.IntegerField()
```

**Models**

```
from mongoengine import *

class tyre(EmbeddedDocument):
    enabled =  ListField() <----- This is the issue...
    tyre_pressure = IntField()
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I couldnt use this feild was version of REST which was 2.6. Once I upgraded to 3.0 and I used the following. Everything worked as expected.

```
enabled = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=4096)
    )
```